# Linux: Recursively find all .txt files that don't have a matching .tif

Tags: find-occurrences

I am using Debian Linux. I'm a newbie. I'll do my best to ask in the simplest way I know.

I have a pretty deep tree of directories on a drive that contain thousands of .tif files and .txt files. I'd like to recursively find (list) all .txt files that **do not** have a matching .tif file (basename). The .tif files and .txt files are also located in separate directories throughout the tree.

In simple form it could look like this...

directory1: hf-770.tif, hf-771.tif, hf-772.tif

directory2: hf-770.txt, hf-771.txt, hf-771.txt, hr-001.txt, tb-789.txt

I need to find (list) hr-001.txt and tb-789.txt as they do not have a matching .tif file. Again the directory tree is quite deep with multiple sub-directories throughout.

I researched and experimented with variations of the following commands but cannot seem to make it work. Thank you so much.

```
find -name "*.tif" -name "*.txt" | ls -1 | sed 's/\([^.]*\).*/\1/' | uniq
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a shell script for this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -ue
while IFS= read -r -d '' txt
do
    tif=$(basename "$txt" | sed s/\.txt$/.tif/)
    found=$(find . -name "$tif")
    if [ -z "$found" ]
    then
        echo "$txt has no tif"
    fi
done < <(find . -name \*.txt -print0)
```

This has a loop over all `.txt` files it finds in the current directory or below. For each found file, it replaces the `.txt` extension with `.tif`, then tries to find that file. If it cannot find it (returned text is empty), it prints the `.txt` file name.

```
robert@saaz:$ tree
.
├── bar
│   └── a.txt
├── foo
│   ├── a.tif
│   ├── b.tif
│   ├── c.tif
│   └── d.txt
└── txt-without-tif

2 directories, 6 files
robert@saaz:$ bash txt-without-tif
./foo/d.txt has no tif
```

Comment: Did as you did.. ran the script on an example and it ran without a glitch. Running the script right now. Approx 600k files throughout multiple directories. Already receiving verbose output of .txt files that exist without a matching .tif. I will followup once the script has finished. Your programming expertise is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I apologize for the delayed reply back. Your script worked perfectly and thank you. I tried to add a plus check to your response but seems I need 15 posts to change the score  of your response. So if someone out there has a few minutes to give Robert a thumbs up I'd really appreciate it. Test as he did if you must. Thank you!

Comment: I didn't realize there's a difference between clicking on the up arrow and the check mark. I did as you suggested. Again thanks! The newbie is learning. :)